# creating printing and counting linked lists using recursion

Tags: c, linked-list

i tried to create linked list as follows but the output comes a fixed list
of two elements and count to be 2

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define null 0
struct list
{
    int num;
    struct list *next;
};

typedef struct list node;

int create(node *list)
{ int n;
    printf("enter the element to end the list finish it with -999\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    if(n==-999)return 0;
    else {
       list=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node *));
       list->num=n;
       if(!(create(list->next)))list->next=null;
       return 1}
    }
void printlist(node * list) {
    if(list->next==null)
       {printf("%d->",list->num);return;}
     else
       {printf("%d->",list->num);printlist(list->next);}
     return;
   }

int count(node *list) {
    if(list->next==null)return 1;
    else return(1+count(list->next));
}

void main()  {
    node *list;
    create(list);
    printlist(list);
    printf("\n%d",count(list));
}
```

*is there any problem with passing pointer to the function.*

Comment: (node *)malloc(sizeof(node *)) is wrong man. You need to write it as (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));

Answer (score 0):

When you pass in a pointer to `create` it creates a copy of the pointer. That is, if you modify `list` in `create` it will not change the value of `list` in `main`.

Try passing in the pointer to `list` in `main` to `create`. This will allow you to cange list inside `create`.

```
// in main:
create(&list)

// in create
int create(node** listptr) {
   // similar code to before except
   // that list should be replaced with
   // (*listptr)
   //
   // the example below will assing a value
   // to the variable list in main:
   // (*listptr) = x 

   // ...

}
```

Print should work as is. It doesn't need a `node**` as it won't change the list.

Comment: thank you for correcting my code to brainstorm and yasir majeed

Comment: if i pass the pointer after allocating the memory initially in main with slight changes the code seems to work.why does this happen?